# Convert S3M, XM and MOD files to lossless and/or and preserve tags

Tags: macos, audio, converters, demoscene

Remember the modules of the past? MOD, S3M, XM, ST? Great, so do I!

I have thousands of modules. But now I'd love to convert all my collected modules into playable files in an updated format, with some of the module tag info preserved.

How can I, in MacOS (optionally using the command line), convert all module files in a folder into a lossless format and preserve some of the tags in the modules in the destination format?

My next step is to place all files into a Plex share :-D

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will likely be best asking this over at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ since it isn't a programming question. From this answer https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/batch-audio-converter-for-linux-that-can-convert-from-flac-to-aac/2406#2406 it would appear GStreamer and gnome-sound converter can deal with MOD files. For embedding metadata in the file, FLAC is the obvious candidate. macOS specific starts to be tricky. If you ask at software recs with the right tags I would be surprised if you did not receive a response